# Search SQLite table if string contains double quotes

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How to search in SQLite if the string contains a double quotes (`"`) character?

When I am trying to search for these my app crashes.

My code

```
public Boolean readbookname(String bookname) {

    bookname=bookname.replace("\"", "\"'");

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select book_name From book_data WHERE book_name=\"" + bookname + "\"", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error log

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'"" (code 1): , while compiling: select book_name From book_data WHERE book_name="'"'"
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1280)
    at ktech4.brilliantinnovator.com.k4tech.DBManager.readbookname(DBManager.java:355)
    at ktech4.brilliantinnovator.com.k4tech.CustomDialogClass.onClick(CustomDialogClass.java:74)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4803)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20102)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: read about the second parameter of r`awQuery`, please dont follow the below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `bookname=bookname.replace("\"", "\"'");` and Change

```
 Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select book_name From book_data WHERE book_name=\"" + bookname + "\"", null);
```

To

```
 Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select book_name From book_data WHERE book_name='" + bookname + "'", null);
```

Comment: i will try and let u know soon

Comment: and what if `bookname` contains `'` character?

Comment: i have replaced it with  bookname.replace("'","\''");

Comment: no , it is not correct way, the correct way is to use the second parameter of `rawQuery` method, from the docs: `selectionArgs You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.`

Answer (score 0):

```
"select book_name From book_data WHERE book_name='" + bookname + "'"
```

try to put your query like this